# jquery script issue on different browser

Tags: jquery, browser, keyup

I have an issue with the following script, it basically turn the colour of the entered digits from black to red if the number entered is >100, or the total of the entry is >100.

The first part is fine but since I don't have control over the total entry, as it is being calculated at the back end (.confirmit-as-sum-field), I can only grab the text being displayed and see if it's over the limit. This works fine in Chrome but not IE, e.g. IE seems to delay the colour changes, there are two text boxes, if the first one is 70, 2nd one is 40 the total will be 110, the total will still be in black font, it will turn red until I have added one more digit in 2nd box to 400, which makes the total to be 470. And it will continue to be in red if i add more digits to either boxes. However if I bring the total to be below 100 for the first time, the colour of the font will still be in red, it will only go to black if i adjust the digit to another number below the 100 mark the second time.

Here is the script, not sure if you could see any browser specific issues here, or alternative ways I can try:

```
//flag numbers over 100%
$('.numberinput').each(function()
{
$(this).keyup(function(){
if($(this).val()>100){$(this).css('color','red');}
else{$(this).css('color','black');}

//flag total over 100%
var sum = $('.confirmit-as-sum-field').text();
if(parseInt(sum) >100){$('.confirmit-as-sum-field').css('color','red')}
else{$('.confirmit-as-sum-field').css('color','black')}
});
});
```

Many thanks,
Roy

---

Here is the backend bits, not sure if that's any help:

```
 var args = ["wix-components","wix-numeric","wix-auto-sum","wix-focus-first","yui-later"],
            yui3 = YUI({
                loadErrorFn: showFieldsets,
                groups: {
                    wix: {
                        base: '/cf_clientutil/wix/',
                        combine: false,
                        modules: {"confirmit-cblib":{"fullpath":"/cf_clientutil/scripts/cblib-min.js?v=2891_P19c","requires":["dom","event","node","oop"]},"confirmit-dedchain":{"fullpath":"/cf_clientutil/scripts/dedchain-min.js?v=2891_P19c","requires":["confirmit-cblib"]},"wix":{"path":"wix-min.js?v=2891_P19c","requires":["node"]},"wix-components":{"path":"wix-components-min.js?v=2891_P19c","requires":["wix","confirmit-cblib","plugin","base","selector-css3"]},"wix-slider-base":{"path":"slider-base-min.js","requires":["wix","event-resize"]},"wix-numeric":{"path":"numeric-min.js?v=2891_P19c","requires":null},"wix-auto-sum":{"path":"auto-sum-min.js?v=2891_P19c","requires":null},"wix-focus-first":{"path":"wix-focus-first-min.js?v=2891_P19c","requires":["wix"]}}
                    }
                },
                allowRollup: false,
                filter: '',
                comboBase: '/wix/combo.aspx?',
                combine: true
            });

        args.push( function(Y) {
            var wix = Y.WixInstance = new Y.Wix( {"formId":"ctlform","debug":false,"capi":false,"offline":false,"defaultLanguage":9} );
            Y.WixInstance.addComponent({"type":"Numeric","hostId":"ps1_1","fieldsetId":"fieldset_ps1","digits":3,"decimals":0,"thousandSep":"%2C","decSep":"."});
            Y.WixInstance.addComponent({"type":"Numeric","hostId":"ps1_2","fieldsetId":"fieldset_ps1","digits":3,"decimals":0,"thousandSep":"%2C","decSep":"."});
            Y.WixInstance.addComponent({"type":"AutoSum","fieldsetId":"fieldset_ps1","questionType":"multi","inputPrefix":"","inputSuffix":"%","scale":0,"sumLabel":"Total"});
            window.wix = Y.WixInstance;
            window.wix.Y = Y;
        window.onerror = Y.WixInstance.handleError;

            Y.WixInstance.fire('ready');
        } );

        yui3.use.apply(yui3, args);


    } else {

        showFieldsets();
    }

})();
```

Comment: A jsfiddle, including both the html and JavaScript, will probably get you a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, it's because you're doing the calculation in the back-end, yet checking for the sum upon keypress. Try making a callback function to check for the sum.

Here's what's happening:

- you enter a number
- AJAX call to the backend
- you check for the sum
- AJAX returns and fills the sum field
- nothing happens
- you enter another number
- AJAX call to the backend
- you check for the sum, find the result from the **previous** AJAX call
- etc...

That's why it seems like your sum checker is always "one keypress late".

UPDATE

Upon a quick glance to the backend, it does seem to make some <strike>AJAX</strike> calls and I didn't notice it allows you to set callbacks. This is probably what causes a delay. So this is what I'd do: I'd set a onchange listener to your sum field element and check the sum and paint the number on every change. Something like this:

<strike>$('.confirmit-as-sum-field').on('change', function(){
        var sum = $('.confirmit-as-sum-field').text();
        if(parseInt(sum) >100){$('.confirmit-as-sum-field').css('color','red')}
        else{$('.confirmit-as-sum-field').css('color','black')}
    });</strike>

This is how it should work for non-form elements: http://jsfiddle.net/FUtb9/1/ (try changing its value from your DevTools)

```
$('p.confirmit-as-sum-field').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMSubtreeModified DOMNodeRemoved', function(event)    {
    var sum = + $('p.confirmit-as-sum-field').text();
    if(parseInt(sum) >100){$('.confirmit-as-sum-field').css('color','red')}
    else{$('p.confirmit-as-sum-field').css('color','black')}
    alert(sum);
});
```

Here it is with an input field you can use to change the text of your sum field element: http://jsfiddle.net/FUtb9/2/

Comment: Also, can you tell more about the backend part?

Comment: Hi all, that's exactly right, i am always one keypress late, but it only happens in IE, not in Chrome though, here is the backend I can find， it is using YUI which I am not familiar with, and I don't have access to the back end files to create a scenario in jsfiddle

Comment: Hi Shomz, thanks for the suggestion, the on change function doesn't seem to change the font colour if the total goes over the 100 mark or not, i'll try to get you a link so you can test it, many thanks Roy

Comment: Right, right, you can only listen to change for input, select and textarea elements (basically, form elements). Can you modify your code to have a hidden input field which it will listen to? I'll update my answer.

Comment: I can certainly add a hidden field in my page, btw here is the link: http://survey.confirmit.com/extwix/test_p2845328135.aspx?__etk=JUVZWVYUCUSO the first page comes with my original script, 2nd page with the on change function included

Comment: Actually, no need to complicate stuff further, see my updated answer and two jsfiddle examples. (Unfortunately, I'm on Linux, no IE, so I can't check your live site, but the code I gave you should cover all possibilities)

Comment: Many thanks Shomz, http://jsfiddle.net/FUtb9/2/ looks great to me, hopefully I will not have anymore questions to ask, really appreciated your detailed answers and patience, many thanks!!!

Comment: You're welcome, Roy! Stack Overflow is a great community for people who post nice and clear questions just like you did, so don't hesitate to ask if you run into more problems.